# How do I force push a feature-branch to Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, feature-branch

I have been working on a (remote) feature branch and after changing the branch history, I want to push it to Gerrit (with force push).

I tried the following command:

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch_name --force

However, instead of changing the branch history, it just pushed the changes on top of the branch.

What am I doing wrong? How can i force-push or change the remote branch history?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
git push origin branch_name -f
```

Comment: This answer would've been a lot better if it explained why the OP's command produced the incorrect result and why this command worked better.

Answer (score 4):

Execute this:

```
git push -f origin HEAD:refs/heads/branch_name
```